# Deep tree navigation with possible actions at any point

Tags: navigation, tree

I'm building a tree structure navigation that could go quite deep. Actions can be performed at child level but you can also select any point of the tree navigation and use an action that will switch on all existing children under that specific tree instead of having to drill down to a specific children ( but you can do that if you want or need )

My concern is regarding the tree navigation and what to show on the right area to avoid confusing the users.

In example one you can see that you can click a higher hierarchical point and have the general action button that will affect everything underneath and also the sub-elements of that with a chevron that would allow you to continue navigation from the right area which does not seem logical ( this would allow the user to navigate from both left and right areas )

[image]

In example two the same behaviour but at a deeper level. [image]

My questions are :

1. Are there any other design patterns that would be more efficient in this scenario ?
2. Would allowing users to navigate a tree from both left and right area be wrong ? ( I am pretty sure it is bad but I don't know how to tackle these situations ...

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see with using a left and right type of tree navigation is precisely using the same type of navigation in both fields.

If...

> A tree view is a graphical control element that presents a hierarchical view of information where each item can have a number of subitems often **visualized by indentation in a list** (*Wikipedia*)

...I would try to find a different way to represent the selection at the next panel.

Examples:

### Nested Tabs

[image: tabs]

### Nested Boxes

[image: boxes]

### Nested Sections

[image: section]

### Navigation Path

[image: path]